# Recyclerview onCreateViewHolder called for every item

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` that show some data downloaded asynchronously. The problem is that there is a significant lag when the items are initilized. After some tests I found out that the problem is that onCreateViewHolder is called for every item and it took some time to inflate the layout. This is my adapter:

```
public class EpisodeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EpisodeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "EpisodeAdapter";

    private static final int NO_POSITION = -1;
    private static final int EXPAND = 1;
    private static final int COLLAPSE = 2;

    private SparseArray<Episode> episodes;
    private OnItemClickListener<Episode> downloadClickListener;
    private OnItemClickListener<Episode> playClickListener;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private final EpisodeAnimator episodeAnimator;
    private final Transition expandCollapse;

    private int expandedPosition = NO_POSITION;

    public EpisodeAdapter() {
        episodes = new SparseArray<>();
        episodeAnimator = new EpisodeAnimator();
        expandCollapse = new AutoTransition();
    }

    //Called when first loading items
    public void swapEpisodes(SparseArray<Episode> newEpisodes){
        final int previousSize = episodes.size();
        episodes = newEpisodes;
        expandedPosition = NO_POSITION;
        Log.e(TAG, "Swap called");
        if(previousSize == 0) {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(0, episodes.size());
        }
        else {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(0, Math.max(previousSize, episodes.size()));
        }
    }

    //Called when downloading other information, this seems to work fine without delay
    public void setEpisodesDetails(final List<TmdbEpisode> episodeList){
        for (TmdbEpisode episode : episodeList){
            final int position = episodes.indexOfKey(episode.getNumber());
            notifyItemChanged(position, episode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public EpisodeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Start createViewHolder");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_episode, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        viewHolder.downloadButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(downloadClickListener != null)
                downloadClickListener.onItemClick(v, episodes.valueAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
        });

        viewHolder.playButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(playClickListener != null)
                playClickListener.onItemClick(v, episodes.valueAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
        });

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            if(position == NO_POSITION) return;

            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(recyclerView, expandCollapse);
            episodeAnimator.setAnimateMoves(false);

            //Collapse any currently expanded items
            if(expandedPosition != NO_POSITION){
                notifyItemChanged(expandedPosition, COLLAPSE);
            }

            //Expand clicked item
            if(expandedPosition != position){
                expandedPosition = position;
                notifyItemChanged(position, EXPAND);
            }
            else {
                expandedPosition = NO_POSITION;
            }
        });

        Log.e(TAG, "Finish createViewHolder");
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EpisodeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int itemPosition) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Start");
        holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(episodes.keyAt(itemPosition)));
        holder.details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.itemView.setActivated(false);
        Log.e(TAG, "Finish");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Start payloads");
        if(payloads.contains(EXPAND) || payloads.contains(COLLAPSE)){
            setExpanded(holder, position == expandedPosition);
        }
        else if(!payloads.isEmpty() && payloads.get(0) instanceof TmdbEpisode){
                TmdbEpisode episode = (TmdbEpisode) payloads.get(0);
                holder.title.setText(episode.getName());
                holder.details.setText(episode.getOverview());
        }
        else {
            onBindViewHolder(holder, position);
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Finish payloads");
    }

    private void setExpanded(ViewHolder holder, boolean isExpanded) {
        holder.itemView.setActivated(isExpanded);
        holder.details.setVisibility((isExpanded) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }


    public void setPlayClickListener(OnItemClickListener<Episode> onItemClickListener){
        playClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public void setDownloadClickListener(OnItemClickListener<Episode> onItemClickListener){
        downloadClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return episodes.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View itemView;
        TextView number;
        FadeTextSwitcher title;
        ImageButton downloadButton;
        FloatingActionButton playButton;
        TextView details;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.e(TAG, "Start constructor");
            this.itemView = itemView;
            number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            downloadButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.download_button);
            playButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
            details = itemView.findViewById(R.id.details);
            Log.e(TAG, "Finish constructor");
        }
    }

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    this.recyclerView.setItemAnimator(episodeAnimator);

    expandCollapse.setDuration(recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.episode_expand_collapse_duration));
    expandCollapse.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this.recyclerView.getContext(), android.R.interpolator.fast_out_slow_in));
    expandCollapse.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTransitionStart(android.transition.Transition transition) {
           EpisodeAdapter.this.recyclerView.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(android.transition.Transition transition) {
           episodeAnimator.setAnimateMoves(true);
           EpisodeAdapter.this.recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTransitionCancel(android.transition.Transition transition) {}

        @Override
        public void onTransitionPause(android.transition.Transition transition) {}

        @Override
        public void onTransitionResume(android.transition.Transition transition) {}
    });
}

static class EpisodeAnimator extends SlideInItemAnimator {
    private boolean animateMoves = false;

    EpisodeAnimator() {
        super();
    }

    void setAnimateMoves(boolean animateMoves) {
        this.animateMoves = animateMoves;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateMove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
        if (!animateMoves) {
            dispatchMoveFinished(holder);
            return false;
        }
        return super.animateMove(holder, fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
    }
}
}
```

Is there a way to force reusing the same `ViewHolder` for every items? So `onCreateViewHolder` will be called once.

I've also set `nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` in the recyclerview.

Comment: dont make the viewholder static..

Answer (score 14):

> I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`

I'm going to guess that your `<RecyclerView>` tag has its height defined as `wrap_content`. If it does, that means that you're inflating a layout resource (and creating a `ViewHolder` object) for every single item in your data set; potentially thousands of layout inflations and object creations.

The recycling behavior of `RecyclerView` only works when the height of the recyclerview is smaller than the height needed to display its children. It's normal for a recyclerview to create a small double-digit number of `ViewHolder` instances (usually however many items you can see on screen at once plus a few to optimize views just off-screen), but this depends on the fact that your recyclerview's size is constrained by the screen size (i.e. you're using `match_parent` or a fixed size).

In the case of a `RecyclerView` with `wrap_content` height inside a `NestedScrollView`, the user won't be able to *see* all of the items at a single time, but the Android framework only knows that you have a recyclerview large enough to hold every single item in your data set and so it has to create a viewholder for every single item.

You'll have to figure out a way to rework your layout hierarchy so that you can use some limited height for your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: The problem is that there are noticeable lags even with few items, like 10. So even if I set the recyclerview as you said there would be lags I guess.

Comment: I have gone throught the entire internet for an explanation. **Finally,** your answer nails it! Particularly, _the Android framework only knows that you have a `RecyclerView` large enough /.../ it has to create a viewholder for every single item_ ... Now that we know this, is there any way to enable recycling inside a `NestedScrollView`? Perhaps by resizing the `RecyclerView` on some scroll callbacks?

Comment: Actually, [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) say you should _Never add a RecyclerView or ListView to a scroll view. Doing so results in poor user interface performance and a poor user experience._